# Convert Java class to vector - Clojure

Tags: java, class, vector, clojure

I am new to clojure and functional programming and I need to convert Java class `org.apache.commons.math3.linear.OpenMapRealMatrix` to clojure vector.

How Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep two dimensional matrix, just below code is fine :)

```
(mapv #(vec (.getRow matrix %))
        (range (.getRowDimension matrix)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a direct answer because converting from two dimensional matrix to a one dimensional vector involves **choosing how to iterate over the matrix**. If we choose left to right top to bottom one approach would look something like this:

```
(->> (for [r (range 0 (.getRowDimension matrix))]
       (vec (.getRow matrix r)))                 
     flatten                                       
     vec)       ;; this step is optional
```

Or if you only have one row then you could just call `(vec (.getRow matrix 0))`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you're right, i didn't clarify how to iterate over matrix. I needed it without the optional step. :)